# Broke off D2+ pin from the F_USB30 header

Tags: pin

I bought a new PC with a Gigabyte GA-F2A88XN-WIFI

I had to reseat the connector and accidentally bent and subsequently broke off the D2+ pin.  What will be the consequence of this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Best guess, USB 2.0 will not work, pin 11 (D2+) is the [USB2 differential wire](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/technical-specification/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.pdf)

Comment: You broke the header and thus it cannot be used